# Isotope layout method not layouting items

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

for my project I'm using Isotope for filtering all the items from my db,
but when no items are found, it should load some from a API,

so I have a function that's called `getAPIitems` and this get's called when no items are found, 
for now I have a hardcoded element in there for testing it,

but the problem is that the API items don't get layout like my db items get layout, they all show up on top of eachother like this:
[image: like it should not]

While it should show items like this:
[image: Like it should]

this is the code for adding the element

```
function getAPIitems() {
    addToIsotope();
}

function addToIsotope() {
    var elem = '<div class="shop_box     apiItem" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">' +
        '<a href="ProductDetail.aspx?productID=1">' +
        '<div class="shop_image">' +
        '<img id="MainContent_Items_LabelImage_0" src="productsImages/2155567690287400.png">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<span id="MainContent_Items_new_0" class="new-box">' +
        '<span class="new-label">New</span>' +
        '</span>' +
        '</a>' +
        '<div class="shop_desc">' +
        '<h3>' +
        '<a href="ProductDetail.aspx?productID=1">The North Face® Cat\'s Meow 20° Sleeping Bag</a>' +
        '</h3>' +
        '<p>Three-season mountaineering starts here with a quintessential synthetic-insulated sleeping bag rated to 20°. As part of the Core series, the</p>' +
        '<span class="actual">€  200.00</span>' +
        '<span id="MainContent_Items_reducedfrom_0" class="reducedfrom">€ 205.00</span' +
        '<ul class="buttons">' +
        '<li class="cart">' +
        '<a ng-click="UpdateBasket(product.Id)">To Basket</a>' +
        '</li>' +
        '<li class="shop_btn">' +
        '<a id="MainContent_Items_Read_more_0" href="ProductDetail.aspx?productID=1">Read more</a>' +
        '</li>' +
        '<div class="clear"> </div>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    $container.isotope()
        .append(elem)
        .isotope('appended', elem)
        .isotope('layout');

}
```

Comment: Do you have link to a live version or a codepen with this? My immediate guess is that your elements aren't done appending when Isotope tries to init the layout.

Comment: I tried running `$container.isotop("layout");` in console once everything was loaded, and that still didn't work

Comment: Need an example or additional code. Where are you calling getAPIitems()?